# Logic operators in JS. What do they mean?

Tags: javascript, logic, boolean-logic

I found some piece of code which contains following loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  tabMap['tab' + i] = { element : null };

  i && (tabMap['tab' + i].left = 'tab' + (i - 1)); //??
  i < 2 && (tabMap['tab' + i].right = 'tab' + (i + 1)); //??
}
```

What do the selected lines mean (the ones with commented question marks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the same as the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  tabMap['tab' + i] = { element : null };

  if ( i ) {
      tabMap['tab' + i].left = 'tab' + (i - 1); //??
  }
  if ( i < 2 ) {
      tabMap['tab' + i].right = 'tab' + (i + 1); //??
  }
}
```

The && means that if it's true, check the next statement, which is why it is put in parentheses. It's merely a shortcut for the above.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. What about: `i || (tabMap['tab' + i].left = 'tab' + (i - 1));` I found something like this somewhere in the code.

Comment: It's like `if ( ! i ) { tabMap['tab' + i].left = 'tab' + (i - 1); }`. `&&` will continue down the chain of statements, but `||` will stop when it hits something that is truthy.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that expressions that are connected with a logical AND (`&&`) only evalute until the first expression evaluates to false (or is falsy). So, the following piece of code means:

1. evaluate expr1
2. if (expr1): evaluate expr2

   ```
   expr1 && expr2;
   ```

In your case `expr1` is the index `i`, which means, that your code translates to something like this:

```
if (i) {
    tabMap['tab' + i].left = 'tab' + (i - 1);
}
```

This if condition will evalute to true if `i` is greater then zero. So, what the if condition should look like is:

```
if (i > 0) {
    tabMap['tab' + i].left = 'tab' + (i - 1);
}
```

The same goes for your second statement.

I personally find not good practice at all to hide the meaning of your code by doing clever things like `expr1 && expr2`. If you want to do something if the index is greater then zero, then you should write it that way. I know you didn't write the code but I just had the urge to say that.